# Tikz arrow originating from a node going east

Tags: tikz-pgf

How I can I draw an arrow that originates from a circular node and goes east for a certain distance.

Comment: I tried to use the latex code specified there but it doesn't work. I am not able to get an arrow that goes east from the circular node. Can someone specify the exact code for this simple problem?

Comment: @visval In this case could you please edit your question to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you already have tried or which code you already have and explain in more detail, where you get stuck or what you don't understand.

Comment: `\node[draw,circle]  at (0,0) (a) {N};  \draw (a.0) -- (0:2cm);`. You can also use `(a.east)` instead of `(a.0)`. Or use `\draw (a.east) -- +(2cm,0);`